# phpymyadmin - Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_interbase.dll'

Tags: php, iis-7, configuration

I am installing phpMyAdmin (4.2.3) on Windows 2008 R2, with IIS7, PHP 5.5.12 and get the error

"PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_interbase.dll' - The specified 
module could not be found."

The file 'ext\php_interbase.dll' is present, the phpinfo() page displays OK (but without a 
section headed 'interbase').

After reading several messages on this error on various forums, it seems to suggest 
that I am missing the file 'fbclient.dll' within my PHP install.

Could anyone advise where I can get this DLL / or anything else I need to do.

Thanks for your help

Comment: phpMyAdmin doesn't use the InterBase library; this is a generic PHP configuration problem. If you don't need InterBase for any of your other applications, as the others have suggested the easiest fix is to just remove the offending lines from your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

As told by @Nathan Check the Firebird extension in PHP (php_pdo_firebird.dll, php_interbase.dll) in ext folder. Adding them in my php.ini file or otherwise if you don't need it just comment it out .

```
...
[PHP_PDO_FIREBIRD]
extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
[PHP_INTERBASE]
extension=php_interbase.dll
...
```

For finding the missing dll follow this link:

http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/07/php-windows-install-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php_mssql-dll-php_pspell-dll-etc/

Copy FbClient.dll it in the respective directory

Comment: link is dead...

Answer (score 0):

This is a database called "Interbase", as noted in [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ibase.installation.php).

You need to install [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/) to make use of that library. Otherwise, just disable it if you're not using it.